# Why doesn't nav.push work correctly on app component page?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using sidemenu --v2 template as the basis for my app which has the sidemenu inside the app.component/app.html page. I'm simply trying to nav.push other pages on the stack, in the example below the ListPage.

However, it results in a page with a back button which doesn't work - it gets stuck on the new page.

Here is my **app.html**

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item (click)="pushPage(listPage)">List Page
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

This is my **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;
  public listPage = ListPage;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  pushPage(page) {
    this.nav.push(page).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
  }

}
```

EDIT: Issue is only with android, ios works fine.

Comment: Try using NavControllers setRoot() method like this, this.navCtrl.setRoot(page)

Comment: Okay can do. And just add the back button myself? Thats why I like push though.